# Python, Eliminar caracteres al comienzo de varios archivos

Tags: python, funciones, script

tengo varios archivos en una carpeta con diferentes nombres, todos comienzan con una secuencia de números de esta forma: 0001 - "nombre", 0002 - "nombre", ... 6308 - "nombre". Quiero eliminar los caracteres que están antes del "-" para que solo tengan el "nombre" de cada archivo.

El script que tengo es el siguiente:

```
import os
list_name = os.listdir()
print(list_name)
list_new = [str.lstrip("- ") in list_name]

print(list_new)
```

Hasta ahora no he logrado que me funcione. ¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de qué debo cambiar en el script ?

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero, la expresión que has intentado:

```
list_new = [str.lstrip("- ") in list_name]
```

aunque se parece un poco a una comprensión de listas, en realidad no lo es pues le falta el `for`. Tal como lo tienes hace unas cuantas cosas raras:

- Para empezar, `str.lstrip()` no está actuando sobre ningún nombre de fichero, sino sobre `str` que es el tipo string de Python. <s>En realidad la expresión no tiene ningún sentido pero por alguna razón que desconozco, en lugar de dar un error, retorna la cadena que le hayas pasado a `str.lstrip()`, en este caso `"- "`.</s> **Editado (gracias a `@Dante S.`)**. Esa expresión es entonces equivalente a `"- ".lstrip()` que resulta en `"- "`.
- Una vez evaluado `str.lstrip("- ")`, produciendo como resultado `"- "` tu expresión queda equivalente a `[ "- " in list_name]`. Esto es una operación booleana que mira si "- " está o no está contenido en `list_name`. Ya que no hay ningún fichero llamado simplemente "- ", esa cadena no está en la lista, lo que produce `False` y al estar todo entre corchetes, simplemente produces una lista que contiene un solo valor booleano: `[ False ]`

Entiendo que lo que querías hacer era en realidad una comprensión de listas, que debería haber usado entonces esta sintaxis:

```
list_new = [ nombre.lstrip("- ") for nombre in list_name ]
```

Eso ya sería más correcto, pues producirá una lista con los nuevos nombres de fichero una vez se les haya aplicado la operación `nombre.lstrip("- ")`. Sólo que tampoco va a funcionar porque `lstrip()` no hace lo que pretendes. La misión de `lstrip()` es eliminar los caracteres por la izquierda en una cadena, mientras coincidan con los que le hayas especificado como parámetro.

En este caso eliminaría todas las secuencias de espacios y guiones que hubiera por la izquierda. Pero ocurre que tus nombres lo que tienen por la izquierda son números, por lo que no eliminará nada en realidad.

Aunque podrías usar algo como `nombre.lstrip("012345678- ")` para eliminar todos los números, espacios y guiones que aparezcan por la izquierda, y creo que para tu caso esto podría funcionar, veo que sería más correcto utilizar una expresión regular.

Las expresiones regulares te permiten ser más específico con respecto al orden en que deben aparecer las cosas. Quieres eliminar el número, el espacio, el guión, si aparecen en ese orden. No está del todo claro qué querrías hacer con un fichero que se llame por ejemplo `4423 - 123hello.txt` Yo supongo que querrás dejarlo en `123hello.txt`, pero si se usara el `lstrip()` antes mencionado te lo dejaría en `hello.txt`, pues te eliminará cualquier combinación de digitos guiones y espacios por la izquierda.

Con expresiones regulares sería así:

```
import os, re

list_name = os.listdir()
list_new = [re.sub(r"^\d+ - ", "", nombre) for nombre in list_name]
```

La expresión regular `"^\d+ - "` significa exactamente "desde el principio de la cadena, una secuencia de dígitos, con al menos un dígito, seguida de un espacio, un guión y otro espacio". Sólo si el nombre de fichero comienza exactamente así, se sustituirá ese comienzo por lo que le pasamos como segundo parámetro (una cadena vacía en este caso).

**Nota** Todo esto no renombra en realidad tus ficheros. Solo construye una lista con cómo quedarían si los renombraras. Para renombrarlos tendrás que usar `os.rename()` y seguramente sería mejor utilizar un bucle normal en vez de una comprensión de listas, del estilo de:

```
for nombre in list_name:
  nuevo_nombre = re.sub(r"^\d+ - ", "", nombre)
  print(f"{nombre} se renombrará como {nuevo_nombre}")

  # He dejado la línea siguiente comentada como medida de seguridad.
  # Una vez compruebes que los nuevos nombres son como tú quieres, puedes
  # descomentarla para que se renombren en realidad
  # os.rename(nombre, nuevo_nombre)
```

Comment: La razon por la que `str.lstrip("- ")` devuelve `- ` es que la expresion antes dicha es el equivalente a `"- ".lstrip()`, pues al llamar un metodo de clase de este modo, el primer argumento es lo que por convenio es llamado en python `Self`. En este caso, el primer argumento de `str.lstrip` es la cadena que queremos alterar.

Comment: Otro ejemplo valido es con `str.ljust(cadena, 10)`, que es el equivalente a `cadena.ljust(10)`. Esto pasa con cualquier objeto de Python, incluyendo los que ya vienen con dicho lenguaje.

Comment: @DanteS. Tiene sentido, gracias por apuntarlo! Yo había pensado lo mismo y juraría que había probado a poner en un intérprete `"- ".lstrip()` y había obtenido error de que faltaba un parámetro, y de ahí mi confusión. Pero acabo de probar de nuevo y simplemente retorna `"- "` así que no sé qué hice mal la otra vez. En cualquier caso, reitero el agradecimiento. Voy a editar la respuesta

Comment: Un placer y honor ayudarte c: